# rbrief complilation problems

Tags: ros, opencv2.2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't get the rbrief package to compile. It seems that the stuff for the orb descriptor is not compiling or it has been disabled in the source code

Essentially the error that I get

scale_study.cpp:(.text+0x30d): undefined reference to `cv::ORB::ORB(unsigned long, cv::ORB::CommonParams const&)' scale_study.cpp:(.text+0x324): undefined reference to` cv::ORB::operator()(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat&, bool)'
scale_study.cpp:(.text+0x32c): undefined reference to `cv::ORB::~ORB()' scale_study.cpp:(.text+0x741): undefined reference to` cv::ORB::~ORB()'

I'm compiling it against the trunk version of cv

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10331/rbrief-complilation-problems/) by [Bharath](https://answers.ros.org/users/719/bharath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not use the rBRIEF package anymore. rBRIEF was an attempt at making BRIEF rotation invariant and that resulted in the ORB descriptor that you can now find in OpenCV 2.3.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0